# Flutter Web httpOnly Cookies not saved

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a Spring Boot web server that gives me an httpOnly cookie (with JWT) back for authentication.

Everything works great with Postman.

But when I send a request in Flutter, no httpOnly cookie is saved in the browser.

I hope you can help me with that!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKEn3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

You need to set:

> withCredentials = true;

Full Code:

```
 Future<http.Response> authenticationFromUser(
  String username, String password) async {
var client = BrowserClient()..withCredentials = true; // <====
http.Response response;
Map data = {"username": username, "password": password};
String body = json.encode(data);

return response = await client.post(
    Uri.parse("http://localhost:8080/auth/login"),
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    body: body);
```